# How to Enable All Rows if One Disable Row is Present jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I enable all rows if one disabled row is present. I have a 2 kinds of buttons inside my table. First button, when you click it, it enables all the disabled buttons. The Second button, when you click it, it enables/disables the specific row it is assigned to.

**HTML**

```
<tr class="${fn:substring(monthInfo.month, 0, 3)}">
  <c:if test="${stat.first}">
    <td class="monthName" rowspan="6" value="${fn:substring(monthInfo.month, 0, 3)}">
      <div class="vertical-text">
        ${fn:substring(monthInfo.month, 0, 3)}<br>
        <img src="resources/images/edit.png" width="20%" href="#" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </c:if>
  <td><img class="editButt" src="resources/images/edit.png" href="#" /></td>
  <td>${weekInfo.weekStart}</td>
  <td>${weekInfo.weekEnd}</td>
  <c:forEach items="${weekInfo.weeklyData}" var="week">
    <td><input type="text" name="cell" class="hours" maxlength="2" value="${week}"></td>
  </c:forEach>
  <td class="weekTotal ibm-bgcolor-green-10 ">${weekInfo.totalHrs}</td>
  <td class="holidayTotal">${weekInfo.totalHo}</td>
  <td class="vacationTotal">${weekInfo.totalVl}</td>
  <td class="sickTotal">${weekInfo.totalSl}</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cell" class="remarks" value="${weekInfo.remarks}"></td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.editButt').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
    return !v;
  });
});

$('.monthName').click(function() {
  $("#test1table tbody tr").each(function() {
    var className = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text().trim();
    var value = $('.' + className).find('input:text').is(':disabled');
    if (!value) {
      disableRows();
    } else {
      $('.' + className).find('input:text').prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
        return !v;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

What happens here is that if 2 rows are enabled. When I click the, the 1st button(.monthName). The 2 rows are enabled becomes disabled, and the disabled rows becomes enabled.

But I want is when I click the 1st Button. Regardless of there attribute, all rows will be enabled.

Comment: can you share the resulting html? is that coldfusion syntax?

Answer (score 0):

> But I want is when I click the 1st Button. Regardless of there attribute, all rows will be enabled.

**Enable all button**

```
$("#enable-all").click(function(e) {
  $("table").removeClass("disabled");
  $("tbody tr").removeClass("danger");
  $("table input, table button").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

**Disable all button**

```
$("#disable-all").click(function(e) {
  $("table").addClass("disabled");
  $("tbody tr").addClass("danger");
  $("table input, table button").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

or a **toggle** button

```
$("#toggle").click(function(e) {

  $("table").toggleClass("disabled");
  $("tbody tr").toggleClass("danger");
  var isDisabled = $("table").hasClass("disabled");

  if (isDisabled) {
    $("table input, table button").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("table input, table button").prop("disabled", false);
  }

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/9Lj2k3fc/)